# In there a better way to instantiate a generic field in a class?

Tags: java, generics

I am wondering if my code is correct or badly implemented.
Here is the class

```
public class HubRequest<T extends GenericParameters> implements Serializable 
{
   private String service;
   private String method;
   private T parameters;

   public HubRequest(Class<T> myClass) {
    super();
    try {
        parameters = myClass.newInstance();
        service = parameters.getRequestService();
        method = parameters.getRequestMethod();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
}
```

Is there a better way to initialize the "parameters" field ? I just want to automate the instantiation of that object.

Comment: what's wrong with `public HubRequest(T t) {
    super();
    try {
        parameters = t;`?

Answer (score 2):

Since you [can't create instances to type parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createObjects) with the `new` keyword, the way you are using is the only way to create an instance of the type parameter inside your class.